# kdialog --getsavefilename target/directory?

Tags: shell, kde

When I use `kdialog --getsavefilename /path/to/specific/folder/`, it opens `folder/`'s parent directory, not `folder/` itself. How do I get it to start where I want it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to provide a generic filename that the user can then replace, such as

```
$ kdialog --getsavefilename /path/to/specific/folder/output
```

This will place the dialog in the correct folder with the "Name" field filled with "output".  "output will be selected and thus the user can quickly change it.